# How to load Widget javascript + css files only if used?

Tags: widgets, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'd like to keep the javascript and css styles used by my widget inside their own files (and not add them to the theme).

But i can't seem to get wordpress to add them when the widget is actually used on a sidebar.

I've tried this:

inside the Class declaration, i've added 2 functions

```
class EssentielleRubriquesPosts extends WP_Widget {

function addFrontendCss(){
    wp_enqueue_style('erw-frontend-css', ESSENTIELLE_RUBRIQUE_WIDGET_PLUGIN_PATH . 'css/EssentielleRubriqueWidget-frontend.css');
}
function addFrontendJavascript(){
    wp_register_script('jq-hoverintent', PLUGIN_PATH . 'js/jquery.hoverintent.js', array('jquery'), '1.0',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jq-hoverintent');
    wp_enqueue_script('jq-tools', PLUGIN_PATH . 'js/jquery.tools.js', array('jquery'),'1.0',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('erw-frontend-js', PLUGIN_PATH . 'js/widget-frontend.js', array('jquery', 'jq-hoverintent', 'jq-tools'),'1.0',true);

}
```

and inside the widget() function:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
        add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'addFrontendJavascript' );
        add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'addFrontendCss' );
}
```

But that doesn't do anything...

Comment: what about this docs https://developers.elementor.com/add-custom-functionality/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wp_print_scripts` and `wp_print_styles` hooks are fired way before your widget function so that is way it's not working.

A solution to that would be to include the scripts in the footer using `wp_print_footer_scripts` hook, take a look at [Jan's answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16208/dynamically-add-scripts-to-wp-widget-widget-method/16720#16720)

Or a much nicer solution take a look at [Sorich's answer to another similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/loading-scripts-only-if-a-particular-shortcode-or-widget-is-present/2304#2304)

Answer (score 5):

Best solution is to register your assets first and then enqueue the CSS and JS inside the `widget()` function of your WP_Widget (directly enqueue, not by adding new hooks).

I have tested this solution and it does work in current WordPress version (4.5.3) - both the JS and the CSS are added in the page footer.

```
<?php
// Register your assets during `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.
function custom_register_scripts() {
    wp_register_style('erw-frontend-css', '...frontend.css');
    wp_register_script('jq-hoverintent', '...hoverintent.js', ...);
    wp_register_script('jq-tools', '...tools.js', ...);
}
// Use wp_enqueue_scripts hook
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_register_scripts');


class YourWidget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // Enqueue needed assets inside the `widget` function.
        wp_enqueue_style('erw-frontend-css');
        wp_enqueue_script('jq-hoverintent');
        wp_enqueue_script('jq-tools');

        // Output widget contents.
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    }
}
```